# Mule junit tests and in-memory embedded database: failing to dispose context

Tags: jdbc, mule, derby, h2

I'm adding tests to a legacy project.  The project defines the JDBC datasource using Apache Commons' BasicDataSource.  I've updated it so that when run from `mvn verify`, the URL (from a test properties file) specifies a H2 connection string.  My tests pass, but during tear down an exception is thrown when disposing the MuleContext, causing all my tests to report as failed.

My current workaround is to set `muleContext = null` in an `@After` method in order to avoid clearing the dispatcher pool, which is where the exception is thrown.  This is hacky in the extreme, but it does seem to be working.  So I'd like to know how to better work around this issue.

The exception is:

```
ERROR 2014-01-23 09:51:32,632 [Thread-1] org.mule.DefaultMuleContext: Failed to stop Mule context
org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: null
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:156)
    at org.mule.transport.ConnectorLifecycleManager.fireStopPhase(ConnectorLifecycleManager.java:78)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.stop(AbstractConnector.java:518)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:225)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:276)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:80)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:120)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:94)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:90)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:72)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:64)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.stop(DefaultMuleContext.java:272)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.dispose(DefaultMuleContext.java:282)
    at org.mule.tck.junit4.AbstractMuleContextTestCase.disposeContext(AbstractMuleContextTestCase.java:262)
    at org.mule.tck.junit4.AbstractMuleContextTestCase.disposeContextPerTest(AbstractMuleContextTestCase.java:251)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:37)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:46)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$1.run(FailOnTimeout.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool$ObjectQueue.access$900(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:2140)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.clear(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1333)
    at org.mule.transport.DefaultConfigurableKeyedObjectPool.clear(DefaultConfigurableKeyedObjectPool.java:80)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.clearDispatchers(AbstractConnector.java:819)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$3.onTransition(AbstractConnector.java:546)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$3.onTransition(AbstractConnector.java:519)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
    ... 30 more
```

I've created a minimal flow that exhibits the problem.  Dispatch any message to `vm://startTest` and the flow will correctly insert 42 into a test table.  The datasource is configured to use H2 at the moment.  I've also verified this with Derby, and included that configuration in comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
    xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    version="EE-3.3.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd "
>
    <spring:bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
        <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=Oracle" />
        <spring:property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
        <!--
        <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:memory:test;create=true" />
        <spring:property name="validationQuery" value="values 1" />
        -->
        <spring:property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    </spring:bean>
    <spring:bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <spring:constructor-arg ref="h2DataSource" />
    </spring:bean>
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="jdbcConnector"
        dataSource-ref="dataSource" validateConnections="true"
        queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0">
    </jdbc-ee:connector>
    <flow name="query-insert">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="startTest"/>
        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint
            exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="putvalues"
            queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="jdbcConnector">
            <jdbc-ee:query key="putvalues"
                value="insert into TEST_TABLE (A_NUMBER) values (42)" />
        </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

In case you want to run this flow, the necessary DDL can be called before your test: `jdbcTemplate.update("create table TEST_TABLE ( A_NUMBER int )");`

I'm testing with Mule ESB 3.3.1, H2 1.3.174 and Derby 10.6.1.0 (provided by Mule).

I suppose that I'm running into the problem that the tip in the Derby section of [the Mule JDBC transport reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Reference) warns about, but the proposed solution on that page (to use jdbc:derby-data-source) is not acceptable, since that would require that I modify a working Mule config file.  I'm happy to reimplement whatever solution the `jdbc:derby-data-source` provides, but I don't know what the solution is!

Answer (score 1):

Split your Mule configuration file in two (DB connector and flows) so you can define a different datasource for tests in a third file and load it alongside the one that contain flows.

Comment: Yes I do that in projects where I have that luxury, and I would if I could here, too.  This problem is, this time I can't: the relevant file is shared between many projects and I don't have permission to change it.   Also, I've used the derby-data-source proposed solution, and it didn't help.  Currently, the `muleContext=null` hack is the only workaround that's working for me.

Comment: Also also.. this looks like a genuine bug; the Mule code was added as a workaround to issue MULE-4553.  If I knew a bit more about commons-pool and how Mule uses the GenericKeyedObjectPool, I'd happily contribute a fix for this.  I don't think there's a good reason for the access$900 error, plus there's some icky code in there, with nested synchronizing on different objects..

Comment: OK, alternatively have you tried keeping the MuleContext up and running across the whole functional test with `setDisposeContextPerClass`?

Comment: Yes, that prevents the issue until the final teardown.  It was my original workaround (in conjunction with @AfterClass `muleContext = null`).  The current workaround is better, in that it provides a clear H2 instance for each test.  But it's not what I'd call a fix: the object pool still seems to be corrupted somehow.  I may look into providing a SpringJUnit4MuleTestRunner and avoid extending FunctionalTestCase, which isn't exactly the Spring way of doing things.

Comment: Well, I guess your next move is to open a JIRA with MuleSoft to report the issue and get a real fix then.